ReactJS password field warning
In ReactJS, I have two password fields (password and confpassword) in a form. Corresponding code snippets as below.
State variable as below
  const [theUser, setTheUser] = useState(
    {
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      confpassword: '',
    },
  );

UI code as below
<td>
  <input 
    type="password" 
    maxLength={15}  
    id="password" 
    name="password" 
    value={theUser.password}
    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
  />
</td>

<td>
  Conf. password
</td>
<td>
  <input 
    type="password" 
    maxLength={15}  
    id="cnfpassword" 
    name="cnfpassword" 
    value={theUser.confpassword}
    onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
  />
</td>

onChange functions as below.
  function setConfirmPassword(value) {
    const newUser = {...theUser};
    newUser.confpassword = value;
    setTheUser(newUser);
  }

  function setPassword(value) {
    const newUser = {...theUser};
    newUser.password = value;
    setTheUser(newUser);
  }

So I have similar code for both password and confpassword.
When I access the page, in chrome devtools I get warning for password field as below, whereas no warning for confpassword field.

Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be
uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a
defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a
controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the
component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components
at input
at td

My question: Even if I have same code for both password and confpassword why do I get warning only for password field?

Not sure if it's the cause of your problem but you should be using the functional version of the state setter... setTheUser((prev) => ({ ...prev, password: value }))

Are you using any password manager browser extensions? If so, try disabling them (eg use an incognito / private browsing window)

In incognito, I get the same warning.

If I use a separate state variable for password like   const [password, setPassword] = useState('');   then I do not see the warning.

Did you try the suggestion in the first comment yet? You'd want that anywhere you're using setTheUser()

Yes, I tried setTheUser((prev) => ({ ...prev, password: value })), same warning

For all uses of setTheUser()?

All uses I have not tried yet, doing now

I suspect some other use of setTheUser() is removing the password property somehow, thus turning it to undefined as per the error message

@Phil, You are right. In my fetchUser function (called from useEffect hook), on getting response from back setTheUser is called, there I forgot to add password field whereas I was adding confpassword field for user. Thanks for your help.
